# SQL Server Error: 10054

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am having problems connecting our server to its local database connection.
(No problems connecting remotely)

See screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot]

I've tried adding SynAttackProtect value on registry but error is still the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are going on to the server and trying to connect to the network instance of the server.  If you are on the machine, you need to use `localhost` instead of the network IP address

Comment: I tried using localhost\sql2005, .\sql2005 and the name of the server but the error is still the same.

Comment: Show the services node in SQL Server Configuration Manager for that machine. Also, open the errorlog file directly ([this tip shows how to do that from Configuration Manager](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2506/identify-location-of-the-sql-server-error-log-file/)) and see what *state* is being recorded. Then match that state up with the states [listed here](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/01/14/sql-server-v-next-denali-additional-states-for-error-18456.aspx).

Comment: this is the error log file [link](http://pastebin.com/LaDjH4w4)
and this is the services node [link](http://i.imgur.com/aqBgmid.png)

Comment: Not sure which user you are using but sa and recsys have several failed logins, are you using either/both of those on these failed attempts?

Comment: im using sa on login. I've tried to connect this machine to other db server but it turns out that the same error occured.